# SED command to remove words at the end of the string

Tags: sed

I want to remove last 2 words in the string which is in a file.

I am using this command first to delete the last word. But I couldn't do it. can someone help me

```
sed 's/\w*$//' <file name>
```

my strings are like this

Input:

```
asbc/jahsf/jhdsflk/jsfh/     -0.001 (exam)
```

I want to remove both numerical value and the one in brackets.

Output:

```
asbc/jahsf/jhdsflk/jsfh/
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU sed:

```
$ sed -r 's/([[:space:]]+[-+.()[:alnum:]]+){2}$//' file
asbc/jahsf/jhdsflk/jsfh/
```

#### How it works

- `[[:space:]]+` matches one or more spaces.
- `[-+.()[:alnum:]]+` matches the 'words' which are allowed to contain any number of  plus or minus signs, periods, parens, or any alphanumeric characters.

  Note that, when a period is inside square brackets, `[.]`, it is just a period, not a wildcard: it does not need to be escaped.
- `([[:space:]]+[-+.()[:alnum:]]+)` matches one or more spaces followed by a word.
- `([[:space:]]+[-+.()[:alnum:]]+){2}$` matches two words and the spaces which precede them.

Note the use of character classes like `[:space:]` and `[:alnum:]`.  Unlike the old-fashioned classes like `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, these classes are unicode safe.

#### OSX (BSD) sed

The above was tested on GNU sed.  For BSD sed, try:

```
sed -E 's/([[:space:]][[:space:]]*[-+.()[:alnum:][:alnum:]]*){2}$//' file
```

#### To remove everything that follows a number with decimal places

This looks for a decimal number with optional sign and removes it, the spaces which precede it, and everything which follows it:

```
$ sed -r 's/[[:space:]]+[-+]?[[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+[[:space:]].*//' file
asbc/jahsf/jhdsflk/jsfh/
```

How it works:

- `[[:space:]]+` matches one or more spaces
- `[-+]?` matches zero or one signs.
- `[[:digit:]]+` matches any number of digits.
- `[.]` matches a decimal point (period).
- `[[:digit:]]+` matches one or more digits following the decimal point.
- `[[:space:]]` matches a space following the number.
- `.*` matches anything which follows.

Comment: and thanks for the explanation. I understood how it works now.

Comment: @ John, Want to ask you one more question. if I want to remove all the strings after  -0.001 what can I do.     

example : asbc/jahsf/jhdsflk/jsfh/     -0.001 (exam : abs sjkfd jks)

Comment: @SKG OK.  I added a solution for that.  You didn't say exactly what you wanted.  I chose to make the match fairly restrictive: it has to be a number with a decimal point and one or more numbers after the decimal point, all followed by at least one space.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a tab between what you want to keep and what you want to get rid of.  I don't have linux in front of me but try this.

```
sed 's/\t.*//'
```

This is assuming your strings are always formatted similarily which is what I take from your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\s+\S+\s+\S+\s*$//' file
```

or if you prefer:

```
sed -r 's/(\s+\S+){2}\s*$//' file
```

This matches and removes: one or more whitespaces followed by one or more non-whitespaces twice followed by zero or more whitespaces at the end of the line.